# Replacing instances of string in URL

Tags: jquery, replace

I am currently doing this

```
var currentImage = $('#compImg').attr('src');
```

This will give me one of two URLs, which are the following

```
http://localhost:8000/images/folder1/Yearly/somename_Yearly_something.png
http://localhost:8000/images/folder1/Monthly/somename_Monthly_something.png
```

The only difference is the words Monthly and Yearly. On the page that displays the image I have a select box, with the values Monthly and Yearly. If they select something, and it is not currently being displayed, I need to switch the image. So say I land on the page and it is displying the Monthly image path. If I select Monthly from the select box, nothing should happen. If I select Yearly, it should replace the URL with the Yearly URL. I think the best way to do this is just replace the occurences of Monthly in the URL to Yearly, because the rest is the same.

At the moment I have this:

```
$( "#yearMonth" ).change(function() {

    var currentImage = $('#compImg').attr('src');

    if($(this).val() == 'Yearly') {
        var newImage1 = currentImage.replace("Monthly", "Yearly");
        $('#dashboardImage').attr('src', newImage1 + '.png');
    }

    if($(this).val() == 'Monthly') {
        var newImage2 = currentImage.replace("Yearly", "Monthly");
        $('#dashboardImage').attr('src', newImage2 + '.png');
    }
});
```

At the moment nothing seems to happen. How can I replace the word if needed?

Comment: Its not as simple as that, it is using a framework to render the html

Comment: The **relevant** html is simply: `<img src='http://localhost:8000/images/folder1/Yearly/somename_Yearly_something.png' id='#compImg'>`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace  use `.replace(/old/, "new")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .replace function in jQuery is only replacing the first instance of the searched string.

You could use `str.split(search).join(replacement)` instead which replaces all of the instances. (As suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1145525/4865622))

You should also remove the `+ .png`, because the url is already ending with `.png`.

Then the code should work and look something like this:

```
 $( "#yearMonth" ).change(function() {
     var currentImage = $('#compImg').attr('src');

     if($(this).val() == 'Yearly') {
         var newImage1 = currentImage.split("Monthly").join("Yearly");

         $('#dashboardImage').attr('src', newImage1);
     }

     if($(this).val() == 'Monthly') {
         var newImage2 = currentImage.split("Yearly").join("Monthly");

         $('#dashboardImage').attr('src', newImage2);
     }
 });
```

Comment: Just an observance: on the linked thread, the answer with the regular expression has a lot more votes.  While you obviously *can* split/join like this, it's non-intuitive, so generally a little bit confusing until you've seen the pattern a few times.  I'd recommend sticking with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.replace(/old/g, "new")` - the `/g` part will hit *both* occurances, not just the first.

Second, don't re-add .png on the end

Updating your code (without other major changes) gives:

```
$( "#yearMonth" ).change(function() {

    var currentImage = $('#compImg').attr('src');

    if ($(this).val() == 'Yearly') {
        var newImage1 = currentImage.replace(/Monthly/g, "Yearly");
        // add here: alert(newImage1) to see what it's doing
        $('#dashboardImage').attr('src', newImage1);
    }

    if ($(this).val() == 'Monthly') {
        var newImage2 = currentImage.replace(/Yearly/g, "Monthly");
        $('#dashboardImage').attr('src', newImage2);
    }
});
```

---

Just to extend on the 'without other major changes' - you can make reduce the code using a regex:

```
$('#yearMonth').change(function() {
    var currentImage = $('#compImg').attr('src');
    var newImage = currentImage.replace(/(Monthly|Yearly)/g, $(this).val());
    $('#dashboardImage').attr('src', newImage);
});
```

you could also extend this to get the values from the select itself, making the code maintenance-free.